# Getting started with Spotify API (for Web App)

Tags: javascript, web-applications, spotify

I am seeking to integrate the Spotify Library of music into a Web App. A custom Web App that I am creating. Not downloading a native app to desktop.

For starters I simply want to create a Search; where users can search by 'City' or by 'Venue' and and I will store these autofill results in a array that will ideally; via URL go to that designated Spotify screen where the users can play their music based on the filtered choice.

**Eg.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: [
             { value: "New York, NY, USA", url: 'Spotify URL of NYC artists search results' },
```

I've downloaded a kitchen sink via git hub to get started and uploaded to a sandbox server.
https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink/blob/master/index.html

Bot nothing is display; any advice on working with the Spotify API and how I could implement it in a search as described.

Cheers for any pointers!

**//
Update:**

I am still confused as firstly; downloading and uploading the boilerplate and /or popular 'kitchen sink' for spotify foundation; nothing displays as the index. And external files don't load as they are referenced as 'views' in which aren't .zipped. Also it mentions `$BUNDLE-IDENTIFIER` which make me think it's xcode or native mobile app specific. I want to create a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent answer is still; 'Figure it out with our scarce API documentation'

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to have a read to the [Developer Guidelines](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/) and start a project using a sample project such as the [boilerplate app](https://github.com/spotify/boilerplate-app).

Comment: thanks for the tip! But I am still confused as firstly; downloading and uploading the boilerplate and /or  popular 'kitchen singk' for spotify foundation; nothing displays as the index. And external files don't load as they are referenced as 'views' in which aren't .zipped. Also it mentions $BUNDLE-IDENTIFIER which make me think it's xcode or native mobile app specific. I want to create a web app.

Comment: The Bundle Identifier is a short and unique string identifier for your application.

Comment: I don't know what your question is, honestly. When you navigate to the app that you downloaded (typing spotify:app:<bundle_identifier>), what do you see?. The "views" is a library that the desktop client provides, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Web App creation, not downloading a desktop app.

Comment: The Spotify Apps API can only be used inside the Spotify desktop client. It can't be run on a standalone browser. You can use, though, the [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/) if you want to perform search operations.